# activiti kickstart - human step inside review step

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I'm using the Activiti Kickstart component (with the Eclipse Kepler) and I need some help with placing a human step inside a review step.
So from top to bottom I have a review step where I placed the human step in case the flow gets rejected. After the review step I added another human step which will get executed regardless if the flow is accepted or rejected.
My problem is that the rejection human step (the one inside the review step) doesn't show it's form like the second human step does.
I'm not sure that this approach is correct one, but what I need is in case the flow gets rejected, I want to send it back to the initiator for inputing more details.

Comment: the rejection human step form (the one inside the review step) shows only a button with "task done"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified the model.xml and config-custom.xml files that are automatically generated and I didn't find my fields in the mandatory-aspects, field-visibility and appearance tags. Added them manually and it worked: the human step inside the review step shows all the fields in its form.

Comment: http://forums.activiti.org/content/activiti-kickstart-human-step-inside-review-step

Answer (score 0):

You should make one step for reject and another step for approve in parallel and that will work with you, don't try to paste both in the same step.

Regards,,

Comment: hi hhtest and thank you for your response. I'm not trying to paste the rejection step and the approve step in the same step. I just want to add a human step into the review step. If you add a review step, it'll automatically add a rejection step: this is the location where I want to add the human step.